# Dealing with protocol in URL-String, using regex

Tags: java, regex

## Problem

In my Java application I have the code

`Paths.get(v_DirBufferdata).resolve(Paths.get(v_DirIndata).relativize(Paths.get(c_FileIndataLocation))).toString();`

with

`v_DirBufferdata` being `"file://workflow/../buffer/"`

`v_DirIndata` being `"/tmp/C4243/indata"`

`c_FileIndataLocation` being `"/tmp/C4243/indata/one_doc/pv.pdf"`

and I would like to get

`"file://workflow/../buffer/one_doc/pv.pdf"`.

however I am getting

`"file:/workflow/../buffer/one_doc/pv.pdf"`.

## Regex-Solution?

One simple idea to get the protocol-slash back is with regular expressions. However I want to make sure that only the protocol error is dealt with - not a folder called "file:" by any chance.

Specifically "file:/" should be replaced with "file://", but if "file://" is already there, I do not want to get "file:///". Also, "file:/" should only be replaced if it is at the beginning of the string. So far I've got:

```
"file:/".replaceFirst("^file:/[^/]", "file://")
```

Obviously this does not work yet. How do I do that?

## Alternative solution

If there is a different solution, which does not require regex-hacking, I am all open for it too.

Comment: Maybe [`replaceFirst("^file:/(?!/)", "file://")`](https://ideone.com/fj6rd6) will work.

Answer (score 1):

Either use negative lookahead:

```
s.replaceFirst("^file:/(?!/)", "file://")
```

or just capture the one character that comes after `:/` and use `$1` in the replacement:

```
s.replaceFirst("^file:/([^/])", "file://$1")
```